# Better readable labels in pygal

Tags: python, radar-chart, pygal, spider-chart

I would like to visualize data with Pygal for this I have to use a radar, unfortunately the X-axis labels have very long labels, which leads to the fact that it becomes difficult to read and the labels are cut off (see picture). [image: (Generated plot)]

```
 import pygal
 from pygal.style import Style

 radar_chart = pygal.Radar(fill=True)
 radar_chart.style = Style(
    dots_size=14,
    label_font_size=10,
    x_label_rotation=20,
    human_readable=True,
    background='white',
)
 # example code
 skill_list = ["aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbb"]*17

radar_chart.add(skill_list,
                [randint(1, 10) for _ in range(0, 17)])

radar_chart.x_labels= skill_list

 #......
```

How can I make the labels more readable without using a legend ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding the following:

```
TRUNCATE_LABEL = -1
radar_chart = pygal.Radar(fill=True, truncate_label=TRUNCATE_LABEL)
```